# Is a muslim husband allowed to get naked in front of his multiple wives?

Tags: sex, wife, husband, intercourse

I know that a husband cannot have sex with his multiple wives simultaneously, but can a husband get naked in front of his fully clothed wives where they can see each other(only the husband is naked), and can the wives play with their husband's body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Awrah and closing the sight of it is an important topic in Islam and the qur'an has emphasized on timings for privacy of spouses in ([24:58-60](https://legacy.quran.com/24/58-60)). As chastity and modesty is an important part of its teaching.

#### It is not permissible to have intimate acts with multiple wives at once, nor with one of them in presence of another

Therefore any kind of sexual interaction, be it a kiss or touching your wife or vice versa has no place in public even in your own room and even only with your other wives. And therefore it can hardly be regarded as permissible as it is agaianst the recommended shyness and modesty (see for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6117), in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:37b) and also in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3483) which all are recommending shyness and modesty)

This means in case of a husband having multiple wives, that he can only have intercourse or any kind of sexual relationship or intimacy with one of his wives in privacy of all of them no matter whether another wife would accept having intercourse in front of another nor even in range of audibility of other wives. See for example:
[Is a Muslim husband allowed to have sex with his multiple wives simultaneously?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25695/is-a-muslim-husband-allowed-to-have-sex-with-his-multiple-wives-simultaneously)

In summary conjugal intercourse and intimacy is a private matter between husband and (one) wife and should neither be in public nor in presence of any mahram nor other wife.

#### Islam orders or recommends us to beware from forbidden and doubtful things and what could lead to them

Further in Islam many things that can lead to something doubtful or haram are prohibited (for example in the context of orphan's property [6:152](https://legacy.quran.com/6/152) or in the context of zina [17:32](https://legacy.quran.com/17/32) and also in the [sunnah](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1341c)). And one is asked to stay safe or remain in what is safe and avoid doubtful matters, by keeping the heart clean:

> Narrated Bahz bin Hakim:
> I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying, 'Both legal and illegal things are evident but in between them there are doubtful (suspicious) things and most of the people have no knowledge about them. So whoever saves himself from these suspicious things saves his religion and his honor. And whoever indulges in these suspicious things is like a shepherd who grazes (his animals) near the Hima (private pasture) of someone else and at any moment he is liable to get in it. (O people!) Beware! Every king has a Hima and the Hima of Allah on the earth is His illegal (forbidden) things. Beware! There is a piece of flesh in the body if it becomes good (reformed) the whole body becomes good but if it gets spoilt the whole body gets spoilt and that is the heart.
> ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:52), [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1599a) and elsewhere)

Allah tells us further:

> So have they not traveled through the earth and have hearts by which to reason and ears by which to hear? For indeed, it is not eyes that are blinded, but blinded are the hearts which are within the breasts. ([22:46](https://legacy.quran.com/22/46))

And especially in the topic of desire, intercourse and passions we learn:

> Allah wants to accept your repentance, but those who follow [their] passions want you to digress [into] a great deviation. (27)
> And Allah wants to lighten for you [your difficulties]; and mankind was created weak. ([4:27-28](https://legacy.quran.com/4/27-28))

#### Nakedness in front of the (one) wife is permissible

The majority view of the scholars is that it is however permissible for husband and or wife to see each other naked, one of the strongest evidences for this is [this](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2794) statement of the prophet () allowing this, and that the prophet () took ghusl with one of his wives, while in other ahadith he was hidden while taking ghusl (alone) by another wife and she described his ghusl. But it is however regarded as more modest and chaste not to do so as the [hadith of 'Aishah ()](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:662) -note that it is rather da'if- is indicating.

For further information see for example in the following posts:

- [What is the 'awrah between husbands and wives?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46393/what-is-the-awrah-between-husbands-and-wives)
- [What did Abu Dawud mean by "nakarah" in regards to the strong awrahness of the thigh?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37135/what-did-abu-dawud-mean-by-nakarah-in-regards-to-the-strong-awrahness-of-the-t/37390#37390)
- [In Islam, are there limits on sex between a married couple?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/in-islam-are-there-limits-on-sex-between-a-married-couple)
- [How to interpret the hadith Musnad al-Bazzar 16/215/8628](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49450/how-to-interpret-the-hadith-musnad-al-bazz%C4%81r-16-215-8628)
- [Clarification about al-Mughni 7-101 of Ibn Qudama](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49641/clarification-about-al-mughni-7-101-of-ibn-qudama)

**Conclusion**
Basically what you are asking for is not compatible with the rulings of Islam, it is neither permissible for a husband to be naked in front of more than one wife, and even more any kind of intimacy which was caused or done in such a situation would be haram.